Projection of $\mathbb{F}^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$ to $\mathbb{F}\mathbb{P}^n$ not a Riemannian submersion
I am trying to solve Exercise 1.6.15 of Peter Petersen's Riemannian Geometry:

Consider $F:\mathbb{F}^{n+1} - \{0\} \to \mathbb{F}\mathbb{P}^n$ defined by $F(x)=\operatorname{span}_{\mathbb{F}}\{x\}$,
where $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}$ and assume that $\mathbb{F}\mathbb{P}^n$ comes with the metric that makes the restriction of $F$ to the unit sphere a Riemannian submersion. 
(1) Show that $F$ is a submersion. 
(2) Show that $F$ is not a Riemannian submersion with respect to the standard metric on $\mathbb{F}^{n+1} - \{0\}$. 
(3) Is it possible to choose a metric on $\mathbb{F}^{n+1}-\{0\}$ so that $F$ becomes a Riemannian submersion?

For (1), we notice that $T_{F(x)} \mathbb{F}\mathbb{P}^n=\mathbb{F}^{n+1}/\operatorname{span}_{\mathbb{F}}\{x\}$ and  $DF_x(v)=v+\operatorname{span}_{\mathbb{F}}\{x\}$, so $DF_x$ is surjective at every $x$, so $F$ is a submersion. In particular, letting $\mathcal{i}:\mathbb{S}^n \to \mathbb{F}^{n+1}-\{0\}$ be the inclusion of the unit sphere, we have that $F \circ \mathcal{i}$ is a submersion. 
For (2), I am confused. We have by assumption that, for each $p \in \mathbb{S}^n$,
$$g_{\mathbb{S}^n}(v_p,w_p)=g_{\mathbb{F}\mathbb{P}^n}(D(F \circ \mathcal{i})_p(v_p),D(F \circ \mathcal{i})_p(w_p))=g_{\mathbb{F}\mathbb{P}^n}(v_{p}+\operatorname{span}_{\mathbb{F}}\{x\},w_{p}+\operatorname{span}_{\mathbb{F}}\{x\})$$
for all $v_p,w_p \in \ker(D(F\circ \mathcal{i})_p)^\perp$. Now, the metric on the unit sphere is given by
$$g_{\mathbb{S}^n}(v_p,w_p)=g_{\mathbb{F}^{n+1}-\{0\}}(D\mathcal{i}_p(v_p),D\mathcal{i}_p(w_p))=g_{\mathbb{F}^{n+1}-\{0\}}(v_{p},w_p),$$
for $v_p,w_p \in T_p \mathbb{S}^n$, with a slight abuse of notation writing $p$ for $\mathcal{i}(p)$ at the end. 
My question now is: isn't the Riemannian metric of $\mathbb{F}^{n+1}-\{0\}$ the same at every point, the dot product? If so, the dot product of two vectors, be it in $x$ or $\lambda x$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}$ is the same, so this shows that $F$ is a Riemannian submersion? But this contradicts the statement we are trying to prove.
I guess (3) would be to find a metric such that $DF$ is an isometry, but that is exactly what I am concluding in (2). Where did my reasoning go wrong?

Note that the projection from a sphere of radius $R \ne 1$ onto the unit sphere is obviously not isometric.
